# Allow Users To Change Background? & Inset Into DB

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, css, background

Basicly What i would like to do is allow my users to change their background and then that data gets into the db under the users table called theme.

For example if there is a theme called tiger once they select that from a drop down box and press save the theme inserts tiger into the db and the tiger theme is their new backround?

I was looking though this cms i have but i can't work out how to do it.

This is the html of it.

```
                    <div class="legend" style="padding-top: 9px;">Thema</div>

                    <select class="inputSettingsTheme settingsInput">
                        <option value="tanzania" {if $user.fetch.theme == 'tanzania'}selected{/if}>Tanzania</option>
                        <option value="steampunk" {if $user.fetch.theme == 'steampunk'}selected{/if}>Steampunk</option>
                        <option value="piraten" {if $user.fetch.theme == 'piraten'}selected{/if}>Pirates</option>
                        <option value="pasen" {if $user.fetch.theme == 'pasen'}selected{/if}>Easter</option>
                        <option value="palooza" {if $user.fetch.theme == 'palooza'}selected{/if}>Palooza</option>
                        <option value="olympic" {if $user.fetch.theme == 'olympic'}selected{/if}>Olympic</option>
                        <option value="normal" {if $user.fetch.theme == 'normal'}selected{/if}>Normal</option>
                        <option value="newyear_2013" {if $user.fetch.theme == 'newyear_2013'}selected{/if}>New year 2013</option>
                        <option value="mystics" {if $user.fetch.theme == 'mystics'}selected{/if}>Mystics</option>
                        <option value="mute" {if $user.fetch.theme == 'mute'}selected{/if}>Mute</option>
                        <option value="love" {if $user.fetch.theme == 'love'}selected{/if}>Love</option>
                        <option value="kenia" {if $user.fetch.theme == 'kenia'}selected{/if}>Kenia</option>
                        <option value="hstars" {if $user.fetch.theme == 'hstars'}selected{/if}>Habbo Stars</option>
                        <option value="halloween" {if $user.fetch.theme == 'halloween'}selected{/if}>Halloween</option>
                        <option value="football" {if $user.fetch.theme == 'football'}selected{/if}>Football</option>
                        <option value="egypte" {if $user.fetch.theme == 'eqypte'}selected{/if}>Egypte</option>
                    </select>

                </div>
```

And this is in  brackets on the same page.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){           

        $('.onclickSaveSettings').click(function(){
            $('.onclickSaveSettings').toggleClass("loader");                

            var theme = $('.inputSettingsTheme').val();

                    if(theme != '{$user.fetch.theme}') {
                        $('html').css('background-image', 'url(../assets/image/general/backdrop/'+theme+'/reception_backdrop_stretch.png)');
                        $('.backDrop .horizon').css('background-image', 'url(../assets/image/general/backdrop/'+theme+'/reception_backdrop_horizon.png)');
                        $('.backDrop .leftBackdrop').css('background-image', 'url(../assets/image/general/backdrop/'+theme+'/reception_backdrop_left.png)');
                        $('.backDrop .rightBackdrop').css('background-image', 'url(../assets/image/general/backdrop/'+theme+'/reception_backdrop_right.png)');
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    </script>
```

Any idea on how to get this working?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the change() event, it's better.

http://api.jquery.com/change/

example:

```
$( ".settingsInput" ).change(function() {
//Set theme
//Save entry to DB
});
```